# Wordpress hash posts

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I'm working on a Ajax Wordpress website and I have some posts inside homepage. 
When I click Show on a post a popup with the post appears and the link changes to example.com/#post-id where id is post ID. This is ok.

I want when someone goes on example.com/#post-3 to accest the post with id 3. I did that too. But I saw a problem:

On permalinks I can't put #.

My question is how can I transform my permalink into a link with # or how can I change the other way? Which is the better option?

Thanks

EDIT:

My current permalink is this:

/post-%post_id% 
and I want to make it into 
/#post-%post_id%

Comment: What does your current permalink structure look like, and what do you want to change it to? Examples would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to change this on links called by `the_permalink()` you can filter it. Using your example

```
add_filter('the_permalink', 'addHashToPermalink', 10);
function addHashToPermalink($permalink) {
    $base       = get_bloginfo('url'). "/post-";
    $replace    = get_bloginfo('url'). "/#post-";
    $permalink  = str_replace($base, $replace, $permalink);
    return $permalink;
}
```

This will only work directly on `the_permalink()`, and won't reflect in navigation (menus, next/previous, etc.). You can apply the changes to all permalinks for posts by using the `post_link` filter. This will not work on pages, attachments or custom post types, however.

```
add_filter('post_link', 'addHashToPermalink', 10);
function addHashToPermalink($permalink) {
    if(is_admin()) return $permalink; // only apply the changes on the front end
    // add more conditionals to fine tune where the changes should apply
    $base       = get_bloginfo('url') . "/post-";
    $replace    = get_bloginfo('url') . "/#post-";
    $permalink  = str_replace($base, $replace, $permalink);
    return $permalink;
}
```